# What is the correct way to make a NSWindowController Singleton in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, singleton, nswindowcontroller, nsstoryboard

I have a sample project as:

https://github.com/ericgorr/nspanel_show.git

My project is a storyboard, document based application. I would like to use a custom segue to toggle the visible state of the inspector window. What I have should work, but I cannot quite determine how to make the inspector window a singleton.

I believe I should start with:

```
class InspectorWindowController: NSWindowController
{
    static let sharedInstance = InspectorWindowController()

//    override func init()
//    {
//        
//    }

    override func windowDidLoad()
    {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        NSLog( ":::: %@", InspectorWindowController.sharedInstance );
    }
}
```

But exactly what the initialization should look like in my situation is escaping me, especially since the window is inside of a storyboard.

Answer (score 5):

You can select the window controller from the window controller scene and in the attributes inspector select `Single` from the pop up under `Presentation`. This will ensure the show segue only uses a single instance of the window controller. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33717201/4055451) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would modify your code:

1. In `Main.storyboard` give your InspectorWindowController an identifier, such as "Inspector Window Controller"
2. In `InspectorWindowController`, implement your singleton as follows:

   ```
   static let shared: InspectorWindowController = {
       let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
       let controller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Inspector Window Controller")
       return controller as! InspectorWindowController
   }()
   ```
3. In `Main.storyboard` delete the segue from `WindowController` to `InspectorWindowController`
4. In `WindowController` replace the `showMyPanel()` and `hideMyPanel()` IBActions with:

   ```
   @IBAction func toggleInspectorPanel( _ sender: AnyObject ) {
       let inspectorWindow = InspectorWindowController.shared.window!
       if inspectorWindow.isVisible {
           inspectorWindow.orderOut(self)
       } else {
           inspectorWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
       }
   }
   ```
5. Also in `WindowController`, remove the `NSLog()` call from `windowDidLoad()`. It causes a recursive call to the `InspectorWindowController.shared` initialization code.
6. In `Main.storyboard` link the Inspector toolbar button to `toggleInspectorPanel()`

The `InspectorWindowController.shared` singleton will be initialized, and the inspector panel loaded (but not shown), the first time it is referenced.

Comment: That is certainly a (old) way to solve this problem, but I wanted to use a segue. With a proper InspectorWindowController singleton, this should be possible. The problem is that it is unclear to me how exactly to override the various init functions to achieve the singleton pattern. If it is not possible to create a proper singleton, that would be good to know.